# Java Multithreading: Thread will not finish run() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand java multithreading, and I'm having some trouble getting this thread to finish it's run method.

I have two worker threads consuming messages off a blocking queue. They're supposed to do something simple to the value they get passed and append the result to a file. Because I didn't want to open a file reader for each I/O operation, I wanted to use a StringBuilder to gradually build up the report, and write it all when the thread was kicked out of it's main loop. The code after the loop, however, never seems to be getting run.

Here's the code that is run in the thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    while(true) {

        if(!shouldRun) break;

        try {
            WorkMessage msg = (WorkMessage) ((BlockingQueue) inputQueue).take();

            int payload = msg.payload;
            LocalTime time = msg.timeCreated;

            String report = "Adder got message at: " + time + ". Result: " + (payload + toAdd);

            builder.append(report);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("ERROR IN ADDER: " + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }
    writeToReportFile(builder.toString());
}
```

The `writeToReportFile` method is what's not getting called. When I set `shouldRun` to false in the controlling thread, it seems to skip the code after the end of the while loop. I don't set `shouldRun` to false directly from the outside thread, I call an internal `kill()` method from outside, which sets `shouldRun` to false internally.

Anyone know why this may be happening? I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here.

Comment: Is `shouldRun` volatile?

Comment: No, but I didn't think I needed to make it volatile because I'm not directly setting it from the control thread. I'm changing it using a method in this thread's class (which gets called by the controlling thread to do the killing).

Comment: i suppose that the `.take();` method you are using is a blocking operation , so even if you change the flag , the code will never reach the `if(!shouldRun) break; ` if a `WorkMessage` never gets received. The only way with the snippet you posted , is that from the class which changes the shouldRun flag , cause an `InterruptedException `, close channels etc , and kill the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Thread#interrupt to terminate your thread, your hand-rolled flag approach is causing problems for you, because the update to shouldRun flag isn't visible and the queue can't stop blocking.

If your control thread calls the kill method on the Worker's object, then your shouldRun flag is getting set by that thread. It needs to be made visible using volatile so that the worker thread (which is executing the run method) can see it.

Without volatile (or using an AtomicBoolean or other means to make this change visible across threads) the JVM is free to keep the variable's contents in a processor-local cache not visible to the other thread, or to optimize the check away in the code that your worker thread is running.

Threads using concurrent classes like the queue need to use interruption instead of relying on hand-rolled flags so that operations on components they include, like your queue, can respond to requests to cancel. Otherwise your queue can't know about your hand-rolled flag so it can't stop blocking in response to a call to your kill method.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the thread is blocked because of the take(). Instead of taking() why don't you test this code with poll(time,timeunit) Method which will wait for specified time and then return so after waiting for specified time it will check for your flag shouldRun and would come out of the loop.

Source :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Also please declare variable shouldRun as volatile.
Reason: Following extract is from book Java concurrency in practice:

*"The server JVM performs more optimization than the client JVM, such as hoisting variables out of a loop that are not modified in the loop;"*

So in environment where server JVM is used , you might end up in infinite loop since, shouldRun variable is not modified inside loop.